# In flask, why "file.read()" when send back to client it will remove the newline, and when write to the file it will have two newline

Tags: python, flask, azure-web-app-service

I'm writing a demo flask application. My goal is when a user uploads a file, the server will process the file and return the file that has been processed to the user. I use the [tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/) in flask website. Now I got confuse about the following things:

If I just return the file to the user use `return request.files['file'].read()`, the browser will get a page with every newline in each sentence removed. For example, if I upload test.txt that contains:

```
line1
line2
```

the browser will display as follow:

```
line1 line2
```

And if I write a file using

```
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(request.files['file'].read())
```

the file named `filename` located in the server is

```
line1

line2
```

in which there are two newline characters in each sentence.

What kind of reasons causes this? The write part: is it becauase the \r\n or \n in the file. I'm testing the write part in win10 with python2.7.

This [website](http://meltsubtitles.azurewebsites.net/) is the website that get a file, and when you click the `convert` button the file content will display in the browser. You can use it to see the first results I'm talking about, and you can use any file to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Flask` reads the file content right. But `\n` is not treated as `linebreak` in HTML. You can wrap the content in `pre` tag, this keeps the formats.

From the website you are given, after checking the html source, what the app got is correct.

---

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html

Comment: I see,  thank you. But why when write to a file there are two newline in each senctence?

Comment: @EvanL00 `write` works correct on my local machine. can you print the result of `repr(request.files['file'].read())`

Comment: It is `'line1\r\nline2'`, is it about the `\r\n` or kind of stuff

Comment: I'm using win10 and python 2.7

Comment: I use notepade++ to open the file, it will dispaly three line, if use GVIM, it will display two line, each line with `^M`

Comment: It is `\r\n` issue, before write convert `\r\n` to `\n` resolves the problem. not sure if there's a better one.

Comment: Yes. More formally, it is the file encoding problem. I upload a file that is in dos type, the server write to a unix type file. and when I open the file, it is the unix type, so the editor treat \r as a newline. This is what I in mind.